# Uniqueness of the probability $\hat{P}(B)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a measurable function on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and $\hat{P}$ a probability on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_1)$. If for all $B ⊆ R_X^c$ ,where $R_X$ is range, it holds that $\hat{P}(B) = 0$, then there exists a unique probability $P$ over $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ such that $P( [X \in B]) = \hat{P}(B)$ for all $B \in\mathcal{B}_1$.

How can I prove the uniqueness of the probability $\hat{P}(B)$?